# Receive “UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found” when packaging java grpc service as a jar

Tags: java, jar, grpc

I have a grpc service, here is the code excerpt:
proto:

```
// proto/campus/graduate/v1/graduate.proto
syntax = 'proto3';

package wusthelper.campus.graduate.v1;

option java_package = 'cn.wustlinghang.wusthelper.rpc.graduate.v1';
option java_outer_classname = 'GraduateProto';
option java_generic_services = true;

service GraduateRequestAgent {
  // Login Login service for graduate
  rpc Login (UsernamePasswordReq) returns (AgentReply);
  // GetStudentInfo Get the student info
  rpc GetStudentInfo (CookieReq) returns (AgentReply);
  //... more
}

service GraduateParser {
  // ParseScores Parse the score page
  rpc ParseScores (PlainText) returns (ScoreParseReply);
  //... more
}
```

and this the server implement:

- GraduateRequestAgentImpl.java

```java
package cn.wustlinghang.wusthelper.campus.graduate.service;
import net.devh.boot.grpc.server.service.GrpcService;

@GrpcService
public class GraduateRequestAgentImpl extends GraduateRequestAgentGrpc.GraduateRequestAgentImplBase {

    @Override
    public void login(CampusCommonProto.UsernamePasswordReq request,
                      StreamObserver<CampusCommonProto.AgentReply> responseObserver) {
        //...implements
    }

    //... other implements
}
```

- GraduateParserImpl.java

```java
package cn.wustlinghang.wusthelper.campus.graduate.service;

import net.devh.boot.grpc.server.service.GrpcService;

@GrpcService
public class GraduateParserImpl extends GraduateParserGrpc.GraduateParserImplBase {

    @Override
    public void parseScores(CommonProto.PlainText request,
                            StreamObserver<GraduateProto.ScoreParseReply> responseObserver) {
        // ...implements
    }
}
```

The weird thing is, when I start the server in idea, and call `login()` or `ParseScores()` , all things right as I expected.
But as I package the server project into jar file, if I call the `login()` and other methods, I received `io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNIMPLEMENTED: Method not found: wusthelper.campus.graduate.v1.GraduateRequestAgent/Login` exception.The problem only happens when I packing the server as a jar file.

If I use some grpc debug tool like `grpcurl` or `evans`, they works well no matter I packaging server as jar or run directly in idea, but I just can't call from the client.

The generated proto code the client use is the same as the server use, and the server log shows that it actually loaded the implement service:

```
2023-04-06T20:23:37.358+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] g.s.a.GrpcServerFactoryAutoConfiguration : Detected grpc-netty-shaded: Creating ShadedNettyGrpcServerFactory
2023-04-06T20:23:37.507+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: wusthelper.campus.graduate.v1.GraduateParser, bean: graduateParserImpl, class: cn.wustlinghang.wusthelper.campus.graduate.service.GraduateParserImpl
2023-04-06T20:23:37.507+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: wusthelper.campus.graduate.v1.GraduateRequestAgent, bean: graduateRequestAgentImpl, class: cn.wustlinghang.wusthelper.campus.graduate.service.GraduateRequestAgentImpl
2023-04-06T20:23:37.507+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.health.v1.Health, bean: grpcHealthService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.HealthServiceImpl
2023-04-06T20:23:37.507+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.AbstractGrpcServerFactory    : Registered gRPC service: grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection, bean: protoReflectionService, class: io.grpc.protobuf.services.ProtoReflectionService
2023-04-06T20:23:37.632+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] n.d.b.g.s.s.GrpcServerLifecycle          : gRPC Server started, listening on address: 0.0.0.0, port: 19090
2023-04-06T20:23:37.640+08:00  INFO 27868 --- [           main] c.w.w.c.graduate.GraduateServiceMain     : Started GraduateServiceMain in 1.024 seconds (process running for 1.417)
```

The debug log is also the same as when it works well.

Even I tried rewriting the client code with Golang, and get the same behavior.

Envirment:

- java 17
- springboot 3.0.4
- grpc-java  1.54.0
- grpc-spring-boot-starter(net.devh) 2.14.0.RELEASE

> I also have tried removing the springboot and the grpc-starter and rewriting it as a prue grpc service, but it's no use.

Comment: Are you sure that in the packaged case you are pointing your client at the right server?  I once made the mistake of accidentally calling a server that didn't have the desired service and was equally confused by getting this response.